# createTasks and createJob command in MATLAB does not work when using nohup?

Tags: matlab, nohup

I use the nohup command to run my matlab program on a remote machine.  Since I have to run the same program by changing some input parameters I decided to try to utilize the parallel computing toolbox functions. I have the following matlab script, say datafile.m:

```
      % This is a matlab script titled datefile.m
      a_array = [0;1;2;3];
      jm = findResource('scheduler', 'Configuration', 'local');
      job_ss = createJob(jm, 'Name', 'unsteady_slab_porous');

      paths = {blah blah}

      set(job_ss, 'PathDependencies', paths);

      for i=1:length(a_array)
      createTask(job_ss, @my_function, 0, {a_array(i)});
      end       

      submit(job_ss)
```

when I run datafile.m  on the matlab terminal it runs fine.  However if I try to execute the script with the nohup command,the job fails. 
This is what I do:

```
 nohup matlab  -nodesktop <nohup_script.m &> nohup_script.log &
```

where nohup_script.m simply invokes datafile.m

I am wondering if it is not possible to use nohup with createTask and createJob command at all, or is it that I need to tweak my datafile.m to get it to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to modify your `nohup_script.m` to block until `job_ss` is complete. In other words, simply add

```
wait(job_ss)
```

to the end. Otherwise, the local scheduler terminates all running jobs when the invoking MATLAB client quits - as per the very last sentence on this page http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/distcomp/use-a-local-scheduler.html

Comment: That works as I wanted. Thank you. The other option I found after some searching was to use the program "screen" as an alternative to "nohup". I have not tested it yet though.